# how to send birthday mail from website without opening website

Tags: php, email

I want to know that can we send mail from website without opening website. If yes please explain how to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please ask specific programming questions here. Give us context, show us the code you have, the language you are using. Don't ask us to do your work.

Comment: Scheduled tasks can be executed on most web platforms without the need to use a web browser by using utilities like cron

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker. Amit & Reto its not your website or forum i can ask any question. If you don't want to answer don't comment like silly person.

Answer (score 2):

If it is on Linux then you can set up a cron job to execute a PHP script once a day (or at whatever interval you choose), without actually having to open the website yourself.

For example you could have a PHP script called `send_birthday_emails.php` which when executed sends emails as appropriate. You could then set up a cron job such as:

```
0 9 * * * php /path/to/script/send_birthday_emails.php
```

That would execute the script once per day at 9am. Here's a reference for how cron jobs work:
[www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

On Windows you can do a similar thing with scheduled tasks

Comment: Thanx Col South. i am working on php and mysql so can i use cron job?

Comment: I have a few questions I need to ask to be able to answer that: Is your website hosted on Linux? Do you have shell access? Do you use cPanel?

Comment: yes my website is hosted in linux. i have shell access and i use cpanel

Comment: Then yes you can use cron :) The easiest way for you to set it up would probably be through cPanel. If you search on your cPanel homepage you should find cron. Let me know if you need any further assistance getting it set up or if you come across any further issues

Comment: i have clicked on corn job but didn't understood what to do. i have multiple websites on my hosting and i want to fetch birth date from mysql db and send it with specific website name.

Comment: Cron simply executes a command, such as `php /path/your_script.php`. So you have to have a php script ready to actually do the work, which you can then have executed periodically using cron

Comment: ok. i have understood what you want to say. I am not good with linux, i will check out some videos on youtube regarding corn jobs and will try to do what you explained. Thank you once again @ Col South.